# Issue with Rosetta 2 installation

Tags: rosetta-2

I tried to install Rosetta 2
I got the following message:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
By using the agreetolicense option, you are agreeing that you have run this tool with the license only option and have read and agreed to the terms.
If you do not agree, press CTRL-C and cancel this process immediately.
2022-06-03 18:19:43.925 softwareupdate[90254:2575164] Package Authoring Error: 002-42534: Package reference com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto is missing installKBytes attribute
Install of Rosetta 2 finished successfully
```

Why does it show the "missing installKBytes attribute" error? I also tried going to /System/Library/CoreServices/ and clicking on the Rosetta 2 Updater. When I do that it says an "An error has occurred. Please try again later".

Eventually, I decided to just test if Rosetta was present by downloading Foxit pdf viewer which is an intel app and it works fine. It also shows up in System Report >> Installation. So why am I getting these errors?

Comment: The error message seems to just be an issue with how the installer pkg was created. It says that the install was successful and you have confirmed this, so I don't really think there is any issue.